# How to use a numerical array literal

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, literals

I would like to use an array for one time only, and would like to not having to declare a name for it, e.g, something like

```
int a,b,c;
void foo(int[],int);
...
a=1; b=2; c=3;
foo({a,b,c},3);
...
```

I am pretty sure this is not going to work, but how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `std::vector` or `std::array`, things become easier.

```
void foo(std::vector<int> xs)
{
    for (const auto& x : xs)
    {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo({ 10,11,12 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an array "literal" only once, consider an rvalue reference to `std::array`:

```
// Declaration:
template<size_t s>
void foo(std::array<int, s>&& arr) {
    // ....
}

//Call:
foo(std::array<int, 3>{1,2,3});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way not mentioned yet is to use a `std::initializer_list`.

```
#include <initializer_list>

void foo(std::initializer_list<int> lst,int i)
{
}

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    a=1; b=2; c=3;

    foo({a,b,c},3);
}
```

or you could use a template.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void foo(const T (&lst)[N],int i)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::vector` or `std::array` as in Nicky C's answer is better.

But to answer your question as is, you may do:

```
void foo(int[],int);

int main()
{
    foo(std::vector<int>{10, 11, 12}.data(), 3);
}
```

Comment: won't this be ending with a parameter pointer to a destructed object?

Comment: I just tested and it seems that the temporary lives through the call of the function and gets destructed when the function ends, so it's OK. Man, I love `C++` but it's a minefield.

Comment: @bolov: Indeed, the temporary is destroyed at end of full expression, so *dangerous*, but working.